# Sass For Loop over Nth Items

Tags: css, for-loop, sass

I'm currently working on a SASS for loop to loop over nth images(50 for example). For every nth-of-type I'd like to increase the transition delay by 50ms. The starting point is 250ms and it seems that the for loop I currently have in the works is not incrementing by 50ms and remains at 250ms at all times.

```
        $time: 250ms;
        @for $i from 1 through 50 {
           img:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
               transition-delay: $time(#{$i}) + 50ms;
           }
        }
```

If anyone has any suggestions or could lend a hand, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use a mixin, you can use a default argument

```
@mixin transitionDelay($default: 200) {
  @for $i from 1 through 50 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
     transition-delay: #{($i * 50) + $default}ms;
    }
  }
}
```

Then include it with an argument...

```
.cool { @include transitionDelay(200); }
```

or without

```
.cool { @include transitionDelay; }
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't even consider that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$time: 250;
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
   img:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
       $itemType: $time + ($i - 1) * 50;
       transition-delay: #{$itemType}ms;
   }
}
```

You could probably achieve the same without a helper variable, but I think it makes things cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of the logic to accommodate my needs but here's a revised version of my loop.

```
@mixin transitionDelay {
  @for $i from 1 through 50 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
     transition-delay: #{$i * 45}ms;
    }
  }
}
```